# Is it a good practice to start a fragment from an adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with `fragment` A. `Fragment` A hosts a list in `recyclerview` which requires an `adapter`. When an item from the list is clicked I want to open another fragment, say B, showing additional details about the item.
I can open fragment B in three ways:

1. From the recyclerview adapter itself where I will have the item position etc.
2. From fragment A using callback from the adapter, since the adapter has all the required info like position, object etc.
3. From the activity, again using callback. If i do from the activity, i will have to add callback interface from adapter to fragment A, and finally to the activity. Looks too much.

I want to know what is the best way to open fragment B.

Comment: there is no best way here.

Answer (score 1):

Hey its not good practice to start the fragment from adaptor. because it will be very complex to find the container of fragment. so please always try to start the fragment from main activity which will be parent of all fragment.I hope its help you.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is always good approach->
       2. From fragment, A using callback from the adapter, since the adapter has all the required info like position, object etc.

"According to MVC pattern adapter is always used for binding view with lists. So adapter should always independent from the fragment so the Single Responsibility Principle will always be handled. So, there should be no dependency from the adapter to fragment but fragment to the adapter. When you call fragment or activity from adapter it will create a cyclic dependency with one another so memory will not clear until you finish the apps. You can call any callback method of the fragment from the adapter which method will call the desired fragment you want."